# Rendering another view on POST method

Tags: python, django

I want to post some data to my Index View and then render the Results page with that information.
However, when i return the Results View on my post method, nothing happens (the Index View doesn't redirect to the 'results_page.html' template)

```
class IndexPageView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Something
        return render(request, r'index_page.html', context)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Doing something with the POST data
        return ResultsView(request, results = results)

def ResultsView(request, **kwargs):
    context = {}

    if 'results' in kwargs:
        context['results'] = kwargs['results']

    print('im here')

    return render(request, r'results_page.html', context)
```

The status code of the post request is ok and the print message shows up on the terminal.
What am i doing wrong here?

edit. Forgot to add that ResultsView works fine when it's called through the urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultsView` should be renamed into `results_view` (as it's not a class, but a function).

Your code should work, in case everything is OK in the part you replaces with a comment 'Doing something with the POST data'.

By 'should work' I mean it should return `'results_page.html'` rendered, but *not* redirect to some other URL.

In case you expect to have a redirect after you POST data is processed, you should return something like:

```
return redirect('your_result_view_name_in_urls', results=results)
```

Comment: You're right about the redirect function. I want to redirect instead of rendering.. However it stlll doesn't work.

I've noticed that it works if i receive my POST request from a form element. If i receive the post request from a jquery function ($.post('', data)) then the redirect doesn't work....

Do you know what it might be?

Comment: Nevermind... I've just realized i can't use ajax if i want django's view to redirect.